# What permissions are needed to load data in a shared dataset on SSRS 2016 Preview?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, bids, reportbuilder3.0, sql-server-2016

I've created a shared dataset in both BIDS and Report Builder. The data source is set up to use a windows service account. I've also tried it with a sql user that is verified to work.

In both BIDS and Report Builder, data is returned. When I go to the report portal and try to preview the data, or try to add it is a dataset to a mobile report, it throws an error:

[image: ssrs error]

[image]

I've given permissions at the root folder level to NT Authority\Authenticated Users and to my department's AD group, with all rights granted.

I'm not really sure what else to do, or where to even check to see what the error actually is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out - it actually had nothing to do with permissions. A fiddler trace showed a 422 and 500 errors.

```
422: the Dataset could not be processed. The 500 said 

500: There was a problem getting data from the Report Server Web Service: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The JSON SharedDataSet Table renderer cannot parse the supplied report...
```

This lead me to check the actual query coming back, which had a Geography data type coming back for one of the fields. When I removed this from the query, everything worked fine.